# Gnuplot change color of bars in histogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

is it possible to change the color of bars in a Gnuplot script dynamically?
I have the following script

```
reset
fontsize = 12
set term postscript enhanced eps fontsize
set output "bargraph_speedup.eps"
set style fill solid 1.00 border 0
set style histogram
set style data histogram
set xtics rotate by -45
set grid ytics linestyle 1
set xlabel "Benchmarks" font "bold"
set ylabel "Relative execution time vs. reference implementation" font "bold"
set datafile separator ","
plot 'bm_speedup.dat' using 2:xtic(1) ti "Speedup" linecolor rgb "#00FF00"
```

which generates this plot:

[image: Generated plot]

Is it possible to make the color of the bars which are below zero red?

Thanks, 
Sven

Comment: You might want to look into `rgb variable` -- adding a third column which specifies a green "linetype" or a red one depending on whether the value is positive or negative.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can mimic this behavior using the `boxes` style:

My test data:

```
zip 2
baz 2
bar -1
cat 4
foo -3
```

And then plotting with gnuplot:

```
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "green"
set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb "red"
set style fill solid
plot 'test.dat'  u (column(0)):2:(0.5):($2>0?1:2):xtic(1) w boxes lc variable
#                  #xval:ydata:boxwidth:color_index:xtic_labels
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the commenting what the colon separated values mean (`xval:ydata:boxwidth:color_index:xtic_labels`).

Answer (score 4):

You could split your data file into two parts, positive values and negative, and plot them separately:

```
plot 'bm_speedup_pos.dat' using 2:xtic(1) ti "Faster" linecolor rgb "#00FF00", \
     'bm_speedup_neg.dat' using 2:xtic(1) ti "Slower" linecolor rgb "#FF0000"
```

Or, if you only need to generate a few graphs, a few times, a common technique is to generate the raw graph in gnuplot, then post-process it in an image editor to adjust the colors.  If you go that route, I suggest having gnuplot generate the graph in SVG format, which will give you much better looking graphs than any of the bitmap formats.

Comment: I think I will try to postprocess the plot. Good idea, though!

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem like histogram lets you do it. May be like this:

```
set boxwidth 0.3
f(v)=v<0?1:2
plot 'bm_speedup.dat' using 0:2:(f($2)):xticlabels(1) with boxes ti "Speedup" lc variable
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can also use linecolor rgb variable and give the color like this:

```
plot 'bm_speedup.dat' using 2:xtic(1):($2 >= 0 ? 0x00FF00 : 0xFF0000) ti Speedup lc rgb variable
```