# Changing bar color in GnuplotPy histograms?

Tags: python, gnuplot, data-visualization

I'm plotting some histograms with GnuplotPy, and I'd like to change the color of the histogram bars. (By default, the bars are red.) The answers in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224545/gnuplot-change-color-of-bars-in-histogram) gave several options for how to change histogram bar colors in plain Gnuplot, but I haven't been able to get these solutions to work in GnuplotPy.

Here's the basic setup that I'm using:

```
import Gnuplot

gp = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(persist = 1)
gp('set ylabel "Accuracy"')
gp('set format x " "') #remove the auto-generated xtics labels 
gp('set xtics scale 0') #remove xtic marks. 
gp(r'set xtics add ("Method 1" 0.15) ("Method 2" 1.15)')
dataToPlot = [6.9, 47.6]

gp('set style data histograms')
gp('set style fill solid 1.0 border -1')
plot1 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(dataToPlot)

gp.plot(plot1)
gp.hardcopy('hist_example.eps',terminal = 'postscript', enhanced=1, color=1) #must come after plot() function
gp.reset() #must be placed after hardcopy()
```

The above code doesn't make any attempt to set the histogram bar color, and it produces a histogram with red bars:

[image]

---

I tried couple of things to change the histogram bar colors to blue, but none of them have been successful.

First, following mgilson's advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224545/gnuplot-change-color-of-bars-in-histogram), I tried adding the following line, but it throws an error and the bars still come out red:

```
gp('set style lc rgb "blue"') #throws this error: line 0: expecting 'data', 'function', 'line', 'fill' or 'arrow'
```

I also tried the following modification to the code, and it threw an error without producing a plot:

```
plot1 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(dataToPlot, with_="linecolor rgb 'blue'")  #throws this error: plot "/var/folders/98/st7ct15n227g1p92mljkx93m0000gq/T/tmp875mRk.gnuplot/fifo" notitle with linecolor rgb 'blue' ^ line 0: expecting 'lines', 'points', 'linespoints', 'dots', 'impulses',    'yerrorbars', 'xerrorbars', 'xyerrorbars', 'steps', 'fsteps',   'histeps', 'filledcurves', 'boxes', 'boxerrorbars', 'boxxyerrorbars',   'vectors', 'financebars', 'candlesticks', 'errorlines', 'xerrorlines',  'yerrorlines', 'xyerrorlines', 'pm3d', 'labels', 'histograms',   'image', 'rgbimage'
```

---

**So, how can I change the histogram bar colors in GnuplotPy?**

Comment: What if you try `gp('set style line 1 lc rgb "blue"')`?

Comment: An alternative hack that might work would be:  `plot1 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(dataToPlot, with_="histograms linecolor rgb 'blue'")`, Note that `lc` and `linecolor` mean the same thing to gnuplot.

Comment: `plot1 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(dataToPlot, with_="histograms linecolor rgb 'blue'")` works! Feel free to write it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative hack that will probably work would be:

```
plot1 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(dataToPlot, with_="histograms linecolor rgb 'blue'")
```

It seems to me that `gnuplot-py` should allow some syntax like:

```
plot1 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(dataToPlot, with_="histograms",linecolor="rgb 'blue'")
```

or something like that.  I don't have a good test case to experiment with right now ...

Comment: `with_="histograms linecolor rgb 'blue'"` works great, but `with_="histograms",linecolor="rgb 'blue'"` throws an error: `Gnuplot.Errors.OptionError: linecolor=rgb 'blue'`. Thanks for all the help!