# Label values & use different colors on bars-gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I want to have values on bars & colors to be different on each bars.
Here is my dat file & script. Also is it possible to label different name for 1st column?

```
host_down.dat
Espoo Finland 20
Marcoussis    40
Franklin park 70

#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
clear
reset
set key off
set term png size 1200, 600
set output "hostdown.png"
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid border
set boxwidth 0.25
set title "Host Down Plot"
plot 'host_down.dat' using 2:xtic(1) with boxes
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240617/5351549

Comment: Hi I tried to use the below one. But not able to get the output using the plot `set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "blue"`                                                          `set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb "orange"`
`set style line 3 lt 1 lc rgb "brown"`
`set boxwidth 0.25`
`plot 'host_down.dat' using (column(0)):column(1):(0.5):2:xtic(1) w boxes lc variable`